# How to calculate date by adding number of weekdays to a input date

Tags: excel-formula

I have a cell where I will enter the date. How can I have another cell where I calculate the date after a specific number of weekdays based on the input date.

Suppose I enter 1st March. I need another date which is 9 working days after this date, i.e 9 days excluding weekends. So if there is 1 weekend in between, then the output date should be 11th March, if 2 weekends, then the output should be 13th march.

Comment: If you think my answer is what you were looking for, please consider accepting it https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

These two functions are what you are looking for:

- [workday.intl](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/workday-intl-function-a378391c-9ba7-4678-8a39-39611a9bf81d) if you want to specify what is *weekend* (i.e. only sunnday, saturday+sunday, ...)
- [workday](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/workday-function-f764a5b7-05fc-4494-9486-60d494efbf33) if you don't need to personalize the *weekend* days

The links point to the official docs where you can find more than one clear example.